# how to integrate comet chat on a stand alone site

Tags: php, database, configuration, chat, comet

i already installed comet chat on my website the problem now is i don't know hot to configure my database to match this values, if anyone knows how to configure a custom php site for comet chat that will be a great help, or just help me read the script to configure my database correctly

```
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_PORT','3306');
define('DB_USERNAME','xxx_admin');
define('DB_PASSWORD','xxx');
define('DB_NAME','xxx_database');
define('TABLE_PREFIX','');
define('DB_USERTABLE',              'users');
define('DB_USERTABLE_NAME',         'chat_user');
define('DB_USERTABLE_USERID',       'cometchat_user');
define('DB_USERTABLE_LASTACTIVITY', 'lastactivity');





/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* FUNCTIONS */

function getUserID() {
    $userid = 0; // Return 0 if user is not logged in

    if (!empty($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    }

    return $userid;
}

function getFriendsList($userid,$time) {
    $sql = ("select DISTINCT ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." userid, 
".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_NAME." username, 
".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_LASTACTIVITY." lastactivity, 
".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." avatar, ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." link, 
cometchat_status.message, cometchat_status.status 
from ".TABLE_PREFIX."friends join ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE." 
on  ".TABLE_PREFIX."friends.toid = ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." 
left join cometchat_status on ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." = cometchat_status.userid 
where ".TABLE_PREFIX."friends.fromid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."' 
order by username asc");
    return $sql;
}

function getUserDetails($userid) {
    $sql = ("select ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." userid, ".TABLE_PREFIX."users.".DB_USERTABLE_NAME." username, ".TABLE_PREFIX."users.".DB_USERTABLE_LASTACTIVITY." lastactivity,  ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".username link, (select storage_path from ".TABLE_PREFIX."storage_files where parent_file_id is null and file_id = ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".photo_id) avatar, cometchat_status.message, cometchat_status.status from ".TABLE_PREFIX."users left join cometchat_status on ".TABLE_PREFIX."users.user_id = cometchat_status.userid where ".TABLE_PREFIX."users.user_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."'");
    return $sql;
}

function updateLastActivity($userid) {
    $sql = ("update `".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE."` set ".DB_USERTABLE_LASTACTIVITY." = '".getTimeStamp()."' where ".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."'");
    return $sql;
}

function getUserStatus($userid) {
     $sql = ("select ".TABLE_PREFIX."users.status message, cometchat_status.status from ".TABLE_PREFIX."users left join cometchat_status on ".TABLE_PREFIX."users.user_id = cometchat_status.userid where ".TABLE_PREFIX."users.user_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."'");
     return $sql;
}

function getLink($link) {
    return BASE_URL."../profile/".$link;
}

function getAvatar($image) {
    if (is_file(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/".$image)) {
        return BASE_URL."../".$image;
    } else {
        return BASE_URL."../application/modules/User/externals/images/nophoto_user_thumb_icon.png";
    }
}


function getTimeStamp() {
    return time();
}

function processTime($time) {
    return $time;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* HOOKS */

function hooks_statusupdate($userid,$statusmessage) {
    $sql = ("update ".TABLE_PREFIX."users set status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($statusmessage)."', status_date = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",getTimeStamp())."' where user_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."'");
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
}

function hooks_forcefriends() {

}

function hooks_activityupdate($userid,$status) {

}

function hooks_message($userid,$unsanitizedmessage) {

}
```

Comment: Hey, I am having the same issue. Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this way:

Make sure that you have created the users table, with the fields chat_user and cometchat_user,
when the participant is logging on your system, you will need to do an insert on this table, just passing the values and saving the id of this insert on the variable $_SESSION['userid'].

Hope it helps...